# How to get darker shadow when a character inside another object’s shadow in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

In my scene, I’m using `AmbientLight` and `DirectionalLight`. As you can see in the images, there are trees and a character. Trees have big shadows, also my character casts shadow as well. The thing I want is, when my character inside the shadow of a tree, it casts darker shadow of itself to the ground. For the ground, I’m using `PlaneGeometry` and `MeshStandardMaterial`.

[image]

I need characters shadow (darker) in here as well;

[image]

I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want this behavior? Three.js is implementing shadows correctly to real life, and your last screenshot is incorrect; shadows are the result of a direct light source being blocked, and they don't get darker when they overlap. It doesn't matter that you're blocking the light source a "second" time, because it's already been fully blocked.

Comment: The last example is from some Unity video, and I think it is the right behavior. When the character does not cast a shadow it looks odd to me. So I need this darker shadow.

Comment: maybe something along the lines of;  haveing a seperat light source for each, have both apply to the enviroment and only one on the charecter ( just an idea never tried it) (give the enviroment an extra ambient light sorce that the charecter dose not have so enviromental shadows are lighter)